# .NET 8 - C#12 - preview try interceptors

Tags: c#, interceptor, .net-8.0

I would like to try the new C# 12 preview function [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#interceptors) but can't seem to get them to work.

The page says

> Preview feature Introduced in Visual Studio 17.7, preview 3.

So I tried using Jetbrains Rider. Because I have seen [Nick Chapsas Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91xir2oUQPg)

My project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
        <Features>InterceptorsPreview</Features>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I used the sample code from this [page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/interceptors.md)

I have looked at the Youtube video some more and saw that the `InterceptsLocationAttribute` was in one of his helper files so I tried adding the code for that attribute to my code project.

Than the code compiles bus still not works. The code execution did not jump to the interception code.

Comment: you need to use install the JetBrains Rider. preview version

Comment: That does not seem to work, i tried `2023.2 EAP7 build 232.8453.124` and then watched the video back, he seams to use the normal version

Comment: Any reason for not using the visual studio?

Comment: @VivekNuna Visual Studio 17.7, preview 3 is not released yet so i just tried using preview 2 but i get the same result

Comment: Got your point, so I’m wondering how can he able to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
Now that Visual Studio 17.7, preview 3 has been released, it works as intended in visual studio preview

I got it working the changes are already in the main branch of https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn so by building that locally i can start a new version of visual studio and run the code in that.
That makes it work, so I think Nick did the same.

Comment: There is a package being developed to use to use this feature to mock code in test:
https://github.com/demonicmetalcs/IntercepTest

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [InterceptsLocation] attribute was not recognized by C#12 compiler as it's missing in System.Runtime.CompilerServices currently.

Although it's in proposal for C#12 but somehow not available in System.Runtime.CompilerServices as of now. We need to add it in System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace and then it works as expected.

Came across one Youtube Channel "Learn N Njoy" where it was discussed and explained. Here's the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-BtY5QugbQ

Answer (score 0):

what do you miss is a helper class with the following content:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
  public sealed class InterceptsLocationAttribute(string filePath, int line, int character) : Attribute
  {
  }
}
```